# Record is not creating even field is exist in table. (Error: unknown attribute)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

When I create record it throws unknown attribute error as shown below, even though attribute is existing in table.

> Error is: unknown attribute 'email__mydata' for CampaignDatum.

Fields in table:

```
CampaignDatum(id: integer, email__mydata: text, first_name__mydata: text, last_name__mydata: text)
```

record to be create:

```
{:email__mydata=>"01auntleslie@gmail.com", :first_name__mydata=>"Leslie", :last_name__mydata=>"Darnell-Collins"}
```

Comment: You forgot a quote after "Darnell-Collins". Also, how do you create a record?

Comment: No dear that quote is not the issue. I'm creating simply `CampaignDatum.create({:email__mydata=>"01auntleslie@gmail.com", :first_name__mydata=>"Leslie", :last_name__mydata=>"Darnell-Collins"})`

Comment: Can you run `CampaignDatum.column_names` and post the output here?

Comment: Could it be because of the double underscores ? I have never used more than one underscore when naming attributes.

Comment: CampaignDatum.column_names
`["id", "email__mydata", "first_name__mydata", "last_name__mydata"]` @Pavan

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna no dear double underscore is not the problem. because all other attributes are populating accurately.

Comment: Are you trying to create the record through controller `action` or from `rails console` ?

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna from both side. same error from both

Comment: If you're checking in your controller, can you put a debugger, before the save and share the `params`.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you have not migrated the database, please run rake db:migrate in the terminal.

Comment: If the migration isn't happened, the column wouldn't be there in the output of `CampaignDatum.column_names`